# Chaincode as external service with TLS: installed but query doesn't find it?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In the [Fabric docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/cc_service.html) example for a `bin/release` script, there's the comment

> if tls_required is true, copy TLS files (using above example, the fully qualified path for these fils would be "$RELEASE"/chaincode/server/tls)

But which files should be put there? How do they have to be named? Are they referenced somewhere? Altogether I even don't understand why they're needed anyway. We already have all certficates in the `connection.json` on the peer side and also TLS certficates referenced by the ChaincodeServer on the chaincode side.

I'm asking because I can't invoke my chaincode and since I don't have additional certificates within the $RELEASE folder, that might cause the problem.

This is happening on chaincode query at the **CLI**:

```
$ export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/config/admin/msp
$ peer chaincode query -C channel1 -n cc-abac -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}' --clientauth --tls --cafile /config/peer/tls-msp/tlscacerts/ca-cert.pem --keyfile /config/peer/tls-msp/keystore/key.pem --certfile /config/peer/tls-msp/signcerts/cert.pem
2020-07-06 07:20:55.290 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 001 Failed loading ClientOU certificate at [/config/admin/msp]: [could not read file /config/admin/msp: read /config/admin/msp: is a directory]
2020-07-06 07:20:55.290 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 002 Failed loading PeerOU certificate at [/config/admin/msp]: [could not read file /config/admin/msp: read /config/admin/msp: is a directory]
2020-07-06 07:20:55.290 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 003 Failed loading AdminOU certificate at [/config/admin/msp]: [could not read file /config/admin/msp: read /config/admin/msp: is a directory]
2020-07-06 07:20:55.291 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 004 Failed loading OrdererOU certificate at [/config/admin/msp]: [could not read file /config/admin/msp: read /config/admin/msp: is a directory]
2020-07-06 07:20:55.302 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 005 parsed scheme: ""
2020-07-06 07:20:55.302 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 006 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2020-07-06 07:20:55.302 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 007 ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{org1-peer1:30151  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
2020-07-06 07:20:55.302 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 008 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2020-07-06 07:20:55.302 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 009 Channel switches to new LB policy "pick_first"
2020-07-06 07:20:55.302 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 00a Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2020-07-06 07:20:55.302 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 00b Subchannel picks a new address "org1-peer1:30151" to connect
2020-07-06 07:20:55.302 UTC [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 00c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0001aff40, {CONNECTING <nil>}
2020-07-06 07:20:55.302 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 00d Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2020-07-06 07:20:55.310 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 00e Subchannel Connectivity change to READY
2020-07-06 07:20:55.310 UTC [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 00f pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0001aff40, {READY <nil>}
2020-07-06 07:20:55.310 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 010 Channel Connectivity change to READY
2020-07-06 07:20:55.315 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 011 parsed scheme: ""
2020-07-06 07:20:55.315 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 012 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2020-07-06 07:20:55.315 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 013 ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{org1-peer1:30151  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
2020-07-06 07:20:55.315 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 014 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2020-07-06 07:20:55.315 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 015 Channel switches to new LB policy "pick_first"
2020-07-06 07:20:55.315 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 016 Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2020-07-06 07:20:55.315 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 017 Subchannel picks a new address "org1-peer1:30151" to connect
2020-07-06 07:20:55.315 UTC [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 018 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0003447f0, {CONNECTING <nil>}
2020-07-06 07:20:55.315 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 019 Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2020-07-06 07:20:55.320 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 01a Subchannel Connectivity change to READY
2020-07-06 07:20:55.320 UTC [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 01b pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0003447f0, {READY <nil>}
2020-07-06 07:20:55.320 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 01c Channel Connectivity change to READY
Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode cc-abac has been successfully defined on channel channel1 and try again: chaincode definition for 'cc-abac' exists, but chaincode is not installed"
```

Ok, let's check if it's installed:

```
$ peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled
2020-07-06 07:27:54.192 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 001 Failed loading ClientOU certificate at [/config/admin/msp]: [could not read file /config/admin/msp: read /config/admin/msp: is a directory]
2020-07-06 07:27:54.192 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 002 Failed loading PeerOU certificate at [/config/admin/msp]: [could not read file /config/admin/msp: read /config/admin/msp: is a directory]
2020-07-06 07:27:54.192 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 003 Failed loading AdminOU certificate at [/config/admin/msp]: [could not read file /config/admin/msp: read /config/admin/msp: is a directory]
2020-07-06 07:27:54.193 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 004 Failed loading OrdererOU certificate at [/config/admin/msp]: [could not read file /config/admin/msp: read /config/admin/msp: is a directory]
2020-07-06 07:27:54.201 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 005 parsed scheme: ""
2020-07-06 07:27:54.201 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 006 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2020-07-06 07:27:54.201 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 007 ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{org1-peer1:30151  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
2020-07-06 07:27:54.201 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 008 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2020-07-06 07:27:54.201 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 009 Channel switches to new LB policy "pick_first"
2020-07-06 07:27:54.201 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 00a Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2020-07-06 07:27:54.202 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 00b Subchannel picks a new address "org1-peer1:30151" to connect
2020-07-06 07:27:54.202 UTC [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 00c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000447800, {CONNECTING <nil>}
2020-07-06 07:27:54.202 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 00d Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2020-07-06 07:27:54.209 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 00e Subchannel Connectivity change to READY
2020-07-06 07:27:54.209 UTC [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 00f pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000447800, {READY <nil>}
2020-07-06 07:27:54.209 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 010 Channel Connectivity change to READY
2020-07-06 07:27:54.213 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 011 parsed scheme: ""
2020-07-06 07:27:54.213 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 012 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2020-07-06 07:27:54.213 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 013 ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{org1-peer1:30151  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
2020-07-06 07:27:54.213 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 014 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2020-07-06 07:27:54.213 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 015 Channel switches to new LB policy "pick_first"
2020-07-06 07:27:54.213 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 016 Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2020-07-06 07:27:54.213 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 017 Subchannel picks a new address "org1-peer1:30151" to connect
2020-07-06 07:27:54.213 UTC [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 018 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0000da8f0, {CONNECTING <nil>}
2020-07-06 07:27:54.213 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 019 Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2020-07-06 07:27:54.219 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 01a Subchannel Connectivity change to READY
2020-07-06 07:27:54.219 UTC [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 01b pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0000da8f0, {READY <nil>}
2020-07-06 07:27:54.219 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 01c Channel Connectivity change to READY
Installed chaincodes on peer:
Package ID: cc-abac:7f7a2b755874ef0c72e6d1eb467f6e65afb488994c80a75f3c5712fcdc9ee095, Label: cc-abac
```

So it's installed but the query command doesn't find it?
And yes - it's installed on the correct channel:

```
$ peer lifecycle chaincode querycommitted --channelID channel1 --name cc-abac --cafile /config/peer/tls-msp/tlscacerts/ca-cert.pem
Committed chaincode definition for chaincode 'cc-abac' on channel 'channel1':
Version: 1.0, Sequence: 1, Endorsement Plugin: escc, Validation Plugin: vscc, Approvals: [Org1MSP: true, Org2MSP: true, Org3MSP: true]
```

This is the **peer log** at the time of the query:

```
[36m2020-07-06 07:31:23.605 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] NewTxSimulator -> DEBU 12a6[0m constructing new tx simulator
[36m2020-07-06 07:31:23.605 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] newLockBasedTxSimulator -> DEBU 12a7[0m constructing new tx simulator txid = [ed5b5de845b99b8b126e1b10d05df3849b9b108c83435f4225fc47c9a3b841c7]
[36m2020-07-06 07:31:23.605 UTC [stateleveldb] GetState -> DEBU 12a8[0m GetState(). ns=_lifecycle, key=namespaces/fields/cc-abac/Sequence
[36m2020-07-06 07:31:23.605 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] Done -> DEBU 12a9[0m Done with transaction simulation / query execution [ed5b5de845b99b8b126e1b10d05df3849b9b108c83435f4225fc47c9a3b841c7]
[34m2020-07-06 07:31:23.605 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 12aa[0m unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=10.131.0.100:51580 grpc.peer_subject="CN=org1-peer1,OU=peer,O=Hyperledger,ST=North Carolina,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=2.128156ms
[36m2020-07-06 07:31:23.608 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 12ab[0m transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
[36m2020-07-06 07:31:23.608 UTC [grpc] warningf -> DEBU 12ac[0m transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to read frame: read tcp 10.130.1.219:7051->10.131.0.100:51580: read: connection reset by peer
[36m2020-07-06 07:31:23.608 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 12ad[0m transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
```

`10.131.0.100` is the calling CLI and `10.130.1.219` is the peer. So is there a connection problem between CLI and Peer?

Coming back to the first paragraph of this question - this is the `connection.json` available to the peer:

```
{
  "address": "org1-cc1:31101",
  "dial_timeout": "10s",
  "tls_required": "true",
  "client_auth_required": "true",
  "client_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----",
  "client_cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nxxx/xxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx/xxxn\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----",
  "root_cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
}
```

Of course, `xxx` are just placeholders ;)

The Chaincode `main()` looks as follows:

```golang
func main() {
    keyFile := os.Getenv("CHAINCODE_TLS_KEY_FILE")
    key, err := ioutil.ReadFile(keyFile)
    check(err)

    certFile := os.Getenv("CHAINCODE_TLS_CERT_FILE")
    cert, err := ioutil.ReadFile(certFile)
    check(err)

    caFile := os.Getenv("CHAINCODE_TLS_CACERT_FILE")
    ca, err := ioutil.ReadFile(caFile)
    check(err)

    server := &shim.ChaincodeServer{
        CCID:    os.Getenv("CHAINCODE_CCID"),
        Address: "0.0.0.0:9999",
        CC:      new(SimpleChaincode),
        TLSProps: shim.TLSProperties{
            Disabled:      false,
            Key:           key,
            Cert:          cert,
            ClientCACerts: ca,
        },
    }
    err = server.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error starting Simple chaincode: %s", err)
    }
}
```